# Seeing element number in UIElementInspector

Tags: applescript

So when I look at a UI item in UIElementInspector, I see stuff like `AXButton`. Great, now I want to perform an action on that `AXButton`, but the problem is I end up doing something like this: (yes I have actually done this, stupid me)

```
perform action "AXPress" of pop up button 2 of group 1 of group 1 of group 1 of group 3 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 2...
```

Now I have to manually try out what button # of what group # of whatever in order to see where that UI item belongs so I can do stuff on it. What I'm wondering is if there's some less kludgey way of seeing what numbers I should put in, as sometimes I can't even find where some `AXButton` is hiding manually.

Comment: This is probably a question for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, UIElementInspector is difficult to use. I don't use it because it's too difficult for me. I'd suggest trying UI Browser [here](http://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser/).

It's a lot easier to find the exact path to stuff... but it's not free. The only other way to find things is to let applescript find it. Suppose you wanted to find a button titled "Press" in a window. You could do something like this...

```
set theButton to first button of window 1 whose title is "Press"
click theButton
```

Obviously sometimes there's groups in a window (and other stuff), and the button may be in one of them, so you may have to do something like this...

```
set theButton to first button of every group of window 1 whose title is "Press"
click theButton
```

I hope that helps.